# I have written a program that computes the collatz conjecture, it works but can't compute very large numbers, how do i get around this?

Tags: python

The Collatz conjecture is a famous unsolvable problem where a positive integer is inputted, if the number is even, the number is halved and if the number is odd, the number is multiplied by 3 and one is added. This cycle repeats until you get a recurring pattern, which is always 4,2,1.

I don't know any other way to complete this task so I haven't tried anything else.

```
if n % 2 == 0:
       n = int(n/2)
       steps = steps + 1
       print(n)
else:
       n = int(3*n+1)
       steps = steps + 1
       print(n)
```

My program does this perfectly well but I want to be compute extremely large numbers (Pages long), When I try to, I get an error:

```
OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

Comment: also note that it's faster doing `n & 1` instead of `n % 2` when `n` gets large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
n = int(n/2)
```

does floating-point division, after which you round the result to an int. Do this instead:

```
n = n // 2
```

Then you will get integer division without an intermediate float representation. Your coercion to `int` here

```
n = int(3*n+1)
```

is unnecessary.

```
n = 3 * n + 1
```

will do just as well.